# Target only the selected data attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, target

Is there a way to select/target only the 'data-season' with the value "winter"?

my HTML:

```
<li data-season="summer">summer
  <ul class="groups">
   <li data-item="beach">beach</li>
   <li data-item="Hawaii">Hawaii</li>
   <li data-item="Beach Ball">Beach Ball</li>
   <li data-item="hot sun">hot sun</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li data-season="winter">winter
  <ul class="groups">
   <li data-item="snow">snow</li>
   <li data-item="glacier">glacier</li>
   <li data-item="hot soup">hot soup</li>
   <li data-item="snow man">snow man</li>
   <li data-item="heater">heater</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

In my Jquery I was able to obtain the string of "winter" from my returning function,

now I want to change the css for snow, glacier, hot soup, snow man and heater only but the css should not apply to summer, how should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  $('[data-item="winter"]').css('background':'red');
```

or

```
  foo = 'winter';
  $('[data-item="'+foo+'"]').css('background':'red');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AKMG7/1/)

ps this also works with css rules

```
 [data-item="winter"]{
     border:1px solid red;
 }
```

Comment: +1 for providing a pure CSS solution – this is how it should be done in 97% of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add, since i spent some time fighting with this issue, that it won't work with dynamically created objects using .data() function, in order to make it I created an attribute on each object named exactly as the data() key i passed to the function.